# Make text completely fill container and clip mid-letter on edges

Tags: html, css, text, overlay

I'm trying to layer some text over an image, but want to allow the text to run off all edges of its container without extending the container. I'm going for something just like this:

[image]

where the background box is an image that's full-screen wide, and the text completely fills and overruns the image on all sides without extending its container. (That is, the image and the text should both be 100% wide.) I also wish to assign each word a unique id for other reasons.

Here's what I have right now: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dduhaime/4xvz7fcg/). So far I haven't been able to get the text to run off the right side of the image unless I set the width of `#text-overlay` to > 100%, which extends the width of the image container.

Is it possible to use something like `text-overflow` here? I'd be grateful for any help others can offer!

Code from fiddle:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

#banner-image {
  height: 0;
  padding: 0; 
  padding-bottom: 10%;
  background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) ), url(http://placekitten.com/150/300);
  background-position: 0% 0%;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
}

#text-overlay {
  position: absolute;  
  max-height: 100%;
  margin-left: -10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 120%;
  overflow: hidden;
  word-spacing: 3px;
}

#text-overlay div {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 4px;
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<body>
  <div id="banner-image">
    <div id="text-overlay">

      <div id="word-number-0">Lorem</div><div id="word-number-1">ipsum</div><div id="word-number-2">dolor</div><div id="word-number-3">sit</div><div id="word-number-4">amet</div><div id="word-number-5">at</div><div id="word-number-6">suas</div><div id="word-number-7">utamur</div><div id="word-number-8">bonorum</div><div id="word-number-9">usu</div><div id="word-number-10">Appareat</div><div id="word-number-11">oportere</div><div id="word-number-12">ad</div><div id="word-number-13">nec</div><div id="word-number-14">meis</div><div id="word-number-15">consulatu</div><div id="word-number-16">vel</div><div id="word-number-17">eu</div><div id="word-number-18">partem</div><div id="word-number-19">equidem</div><div id="word-number-20">duo</div><div id="word-number-21">ne</div><div id="word-number-22">Affert</div><div id="word-number-23">corrumpit</div><div id="word-number-24">no</div><div id="word-number-25">eos</div><div id="word-number-26">Te</div><div id="word-number-27">cum</div><div id="word-number-28">appareat</div><div id="word-number-29">urbanitas</div><div id="word-number-30">laudem</div><div id="word-number-31">meliore</div><div id="word-number-32">appellantur</div><div id="word-number-33">mel</div><div id="word-number-34">te</div><div id="word-number-35">Quo</div><div id="word-number-36">no</div><div id="word-number-37">noster</div><div id="word-number-38">periculis</div><div id="word-number-39">accusamus</div><div id="word-number-40">tale</div><div id="word-number-41">scriptorem</div><div id="word-number-42">ad</div><div id="word-number-43">quo</div><div id="word-number-44">Nec</div><div id="word-number-45">tale</div><div id="word-number-46">partiendo</div><div id="word-number-47">id</div><div id="word-number-48">Eros</div><div id="word-number-49">aliquam</div><div id="word-number-50">vix</div><div id="word-number-51">ei</div><div id="word-number-52">ne</div><div id="word-number-53">eos</div><div id="word-number-54">nulla</div><div id="word-number-55">dolor</div><div id="word-number-56">disputationi</div><div id="word-number-57">No</div><div id="word-number-58">sit</div><div id="word-number-59">soleat</div><div id="word-number-60">facete</div><div id="word-number-61">efficiendi</div><div id="word-number-62">Eu</div><div id="word-number-63">animal</div><div id="word-number-64">integre</div><div id="word-number-65">sed</div><div id="word-number-66">sea</div><div id="word-number-67">no</div><div id="word-number-68">quaeque</div><div id="word-number-69">reformidans</div><div id="word-number-70">His</div><div id="word-number-71">ne</div><div id="word-number-72">homero</div><div id="word-number-73">tritani</div><div id="word-number-74">sed</div><div id="word-number-75">ea</div><div id="word-number-76">odio</div><div id="word-number-77">labore</div><div id="word-number-78">Odio</div><div id="word-number-79">delenit</div><div id="word-number-80">referrentur</div><div id="word-number-81">mel</div><div id="word-number-82">at</div><div id="word-number-83">has</div><div id="word-number-84">an</div><div id="word-number-85">etiam</div><div id="word-number-86">soluta</div><div id="word-number-87">molestie</div><div id="word-number-88">prima</div><div id="word-number-89">cotidieque</div><div id="word-number-90">ea</div><div id="word-number-91">eos</div><div id="word-number-92">Vix</div><div id="word-number-93">iusto</div><div id="word-number-94">tollit</div><div id="word-number-95">aliquid</div><div id="word-number-96">no</div><div id="word-number-97">audiam</div><div id="word-number-98">utamur</div><div id="word-number-99">prodesset</div><div id="word-number-100">ad</div><div id="word-number-101">pri</div><div id="word-number-102">cum</div><div id="word-number-103">dictas</div><div id="word-number-104">reformidans</div><div id="word-number-105">instructior</div><div id="word-number-106">ut</div><div id="word-number-107">Error</div><div id="word-number-108">quidam</div><div id="word-number-109">eu</div><div id="word-number-110">vel</div><div id="word-number-111">at</div><div id="word-number-112">mei</div><div id="word-number-113">aliquip</div><div id="word-number-114">volumus</div><div id="word-number-115">Ei</div><div id="word-number-116">regione</div><div id="word-number-117">aliquid</div><div id="word-number-118">quaerendum</div><div id="word-number-119">est</div><div id="word-number-120">Vel</div><div id="word-number-121">eius</div><div id="word-number-122">malorum</div><div id="word-number-123">at</div><div id="word-number-124">molestie</div><div id="word-number-125">copiosae</div><div id="word-number-126">interesset</div><div id="word-number-127">et</div><div id="word-number-128">cum</div><div id="word-number-129">Cum</div><div id="word-number-130">lorem</div><div id="word-number-131">splendide</div><div id="word-number-132">at</div><div id="word-number-133">debet</div><div id="word-number-134">everti</div><div id="word-number-135">maiestatis</div><div id="word-number-136">ut</div><div id="word-number-137">nam</div><div id="word-number-138">No</div><div id="word-number-139">vim</div><div id="word-number-140">putant</div><div id="word-number-141">liberavisse</div><div id="word-number-142">Ad</div><div id="word-number-143">euismod</div><div id="word-number-144">posidonium</div><div id="word-number-145">his</div><div id="word-number-146">graece</div><div id="word-number-147">quidam</div><div id="word-number-148">utroque</div><div id="word-number-149">eum</div><div id="word-number-150">te</div><div id="word-number-151">Nec</div><div id="word-number-152">ei</div><div id="word-number-153">commodo</div><div id="word-number-154">mentitum</div><div id="word-number-155">te</div><div id="word-number-156">his</div><div id="word-number-157">wisi</div><div id="word-number-158">detracto</div><div id="word-number-159">voluptaria</div><div id="word-number-160">Mei</div><div id="word-number-161">oratio</div><div id="word-number-162">antiopam</div><div id="word-number-163">contentiones</div><div id="word-number-164">et</div><div id="word-number-165">ex</div><div id="word-number-166">animal</div><div id="word-number-167">accommodare</div><div id="word-number-168">mei</div><div id="word-number-169">nullam</div><div id="word-number-170">admodum</div><div id="word-number-171">has</div><div id="word-number-172">at</div><div id="word-number-173">Ne</div><div id="word-number-174">tempor</div><div id="word-number-175">argumentum</div><div id="word-number-176">signiferumque</div><div id="word-number-177">quo</div><div id="word-number-178">nec</div><div id="word-number-179">ea</div><div id="word-number-180">feugiat</div><div id="word-number-181">postulant</div><div id="word-number-182">pri</div><div id="word-number-183">prima</div><div id="word-number-184">labore</div><div id="word-number-185">facete</div><div id="word-number-186">ut</div><div id="word-number-187">Eum</div><div id="word-number-188">gubergren</div><div id="word-number-189">consequat</div><div id="word-number-190">ut</div><div id="word-number-191">Alienum</div><div id="word-number-192">insolens</div><div id="word-number-193">evertitur</div><div id="word-number-194">est</div><div id="word-number-195">an</div><div id="word-number-196">Has</div><div id="word-number-197">ex</div><div id="word-number-198">labores</div><div id="word-number-199">tibique</div><div id="word-number-200">omittantur</div>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please include a minimal, snippet of the problem code here.

Comment: Is the fiddle not minimal enough?

Comment: The problem with fiddles is, if that should get deleted for any reason, this question and the answers will be useless to anyone else in the future.

Comment: I hear that; I just updated the question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[working fiddle first](https://jsfiddle.net/k8kn2vaf/)

1. Remove the margins and weird width and heights. Text should be 100% width, 100% height, no margin, no padding.
2. Set overflow: hidden on the *parent* container (so the text hides when it overflows)
3. Now you have text which fills the container completely, no space on the sides, no overflow.
4. Use transform: scale(1.1) (any number would work) to make the text slightly bigger so it spills out ever so slightly.

   ```
   #banner-image {
       height: 0;
       padding: 0; 
       padding-bottom: 40%;
       background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) ), url(http://placekitten.com/150/300);
       background-position: 0% 0%;
       background-size: 100%;
       background-repeat: no-repeat;
       position: relative;
       overflow: hidden;
   }

   #text-overlay {
       position: absolute;  
       width: 100%;
       height: 100%;
       overflow: hidden;
       word-spacing: 3px;
       transform: scale(1.1);
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks @tayvano! I wanted the text on the right edge to also be clipped right at the right edge. Do you have a sense how that might be possible?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? You can try the transform-origin property, which will allow you to select where it scales from. By default it scales from center. https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transform-origin/

Comment: Or maybe text-align: justify?

Comment: Is it possible to text-align: justify a grid of divs? I can achieve something like this with flexbox (setting `display: flex; flex-flow: row wrap;` on the text container and `flex-grow: 1;` on the individual word divs). That said, I want the the individual text divs to be clipped at their right-most edge, as in my sample image above. Does that make sense?

Comment: I'm not sure if my response made sense, but this is essentially what I'm going for, except I'd like the spaces between words to be more consistent: https://jsfiddle.net/dduhaime/4xvz7fcg/1/

Comment: I think I could help you better if I understood why the individual divs are in there. However, check this fiddle and see if that better matches what you are going for. https://jsfiddle.net/5Lj8Ltv5/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108011/discussion-between-duhaime-and-tayvano).